# Drop duplicate row, If contain all same value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` as below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'first' : ['John', 'Mary','Peter'],
                      'last' : ['Mary', 'John','Mary']})

df
Out[700]: 
   first  last
0   John  Mary
1   Mary  John
2  Peter  Mary
```

I want to drop the duplicate when row contain the same value 
In this case, the expected out put will be :

```
   first  last  
0   John  Mary  
2  Peter  Mary
```

Below is my approach so far:

```
df['DropKey']=df.apply(lambda x: ''.join(sorted(pd.Series(x))),axis=1)
df.drop_duplicates('DropKey')
```

Are there any efficient way to achieve this ?

My real data size :

```
df.shape
Out[709]: (10000, 607)
```

Comment: Can you help with bad information on this SO answer -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/48346011/6361531

Comment: @ScottBoston sure

Comment: @piRSquared will adding sort=False in value_count will solve this ? Thank you Sir for point it out

Comment: @piRSquared yep , I will fix that , will adding sort_values, thank you  :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [13]: pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=df.columns).drop_duplicates()
Out[13]:
  first   last
0  John   Mary
2  Mary  Peter
```

or:

```
In [18]: df.values.sort(axis=1)  # NOTE: it sorts DF in-place

In [19]: df
Out[19]:
  first   last
0  John   Mary
1  John   Mary
2  Mary  Peter

In [20]: df.drop_duplicates()
Out[20]:
  first   last
0  John   Mary
2  Mary  Peter
```

Comment: In your second method, when you do a `sort`, how did it did sort from different columns? Is it because `axis=1`. OP has `mary` and `john` in the 1st index?

Comment: Thank you ~ seems like I need to read the numpy manuel again :)

Comment: @i.n.n.m, `df.values` returns numpy NDArray. When we do `ndarray.sort(axis=1)` - it doesn't care of Pandas columns...

Comment: Hi, One more question , after this , all the column order will changed . Like Peter  Mary  to Mary  Peter

Comment: Got it , in my case,  the order is not that important

Comment: @Wen, if it would be an issue - we could use `df.duplicated()` instead and drop rows by indices...

Comment: Thanks, I got the same out put by `df.loc[pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=df.columns).drop_duplicates().index]`

Comment: @Wen, I meant something like: `df.loc[~pd.DataFrame(np.sort(df.values, axis=1), columns=df.columns).duplicated()]`