# Finding rows with doublicated data in two columns and only keep the one where value in third column is lowest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set

I have a dataFrame with three columns. I want to find rows that carry the same information (regardless of the order of appearence in the columns). I want to remove all rows with redundand information but keep the one with the lowest value in the third column:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({"Dependend variable": ["A", "B", "C"], "Independend variable": ["B", "A", "D"], "pvalue": [0.001, 0.005, 0.001]})

Out[1]: 
  Dependend variable Independend variable  pvalue
0                  A                    B   0.001
1                  B                    A   0.005
2                  C                    D   0.001
```

What´s a good, pythonic way to obtain this dataFrame

```
Out[]: 
  Dependend variable Independend variable  pvalue
0                  A                    B   0.001
1                  C                    D   0.001
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45701346/drop-duplicate-row-if-contain-all-same-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can sort both columns by [`numpy.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) and then [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for minimal values:

```
sort1 = np.sort(df[['Dependend variable','Independend variable']], axis=1)
df[['a','b']] = pd.DataFrame(sort1, index=df.index)
print (df)
  Dependend variable Independend variable  pvalue  a  b
0                  A                    B   0.001  A  B
1                  B                    A   0.005  A  B
2                  C                    D   0.001  C  D

df = df.sort_values(['a','b','pvalue']).drop_duplicates(['a','b']).drop(['a','b'],1)
print (df)
  Dependend variable Independend variable  pvalue
0                  A                    B   0.001
2                  C                    D   0.001
```

Comment: Yep, you had the quicker one for larger sets +1 but I think the one I have is more readable :D

Answer (score 3):

I suggest creating a boolean mask using the values in relevant columns and pass that to the dataframe.

```
df =pd.DataFrame({"Dependend variable": ["A", "B", "C"], 
                 "Independend variable": ["B", "A", "D"], "pvalue": [0.001, 0.005, 0.001]})

cols = ['Dependend variable','Independend variable']
df.sort_values('pvalue',inplace=True)
mask = pd.Series(tuple(sorted(x)) for x in df[cols].values).duplicated(keep=False)
df = df[mask]

print(df)
```

Returns:

```
  Dependend variable Independend variable  pvalue
0                  A                    B   0.001
2                  C                    D   0.001
```

---

**Time comparison for this small subset, for larger jezraels can be quicker**

> jezrael: 100 loops, best of 3: 6.5 ms per loop
>
> jezrael: 100 loops, best of 3: 7.74 ms per loop (large set) *1000
>
> antonvbr: 100 loops, best of 3: 3.09 ms per loop
>
> antonvbr: 100 loops, best of 3: 12.9 ms per loop (larget set) *1000